# wxPython DrawRectangle Not Filled with Black Background

Tags: python, wxpython, drawing

I am using python 2.7 and the most up to date version of wxpython for it (3.0).

I am trying to draw a rectangle that is not filled.  When I run the code below, it draws a red rectangle with the proper thickness, but the inside is white and not my background color (black).

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="Maze")
    self.SetBackgroundColour('black')
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

def OnPaint(self, event=None):
    self.dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
    self.dc.Clear()
    self.dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.RED, 2))
    self.dc.DrawRectangle(50, 50, 50, 50)
```

I don't really understand why I am having this problem and any help would be greatly appreciated.  I apologize if this is a trivial answer, as I am new to wxpython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DrawRectangle is drawed with the current pen and filled with the current brush. So you must also call self.dc.SetBrush.

Comment: And setting it to `wx.NullBrush` will tell the DC to draw nothing for the rectangle's fill.